# How to have ranger for linux open up files that are images or videos?

Tags: ranger

I'm a complete noob to sudo commands or even bash but I have no direction in how to start opening files with ranger. Barely experience with linux, but I do know how to install using sudo apt install. When it gives the prompt to :open_with I don't know what files I can open it with or where to find the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [user guide](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Official-User-Guide):

> To open a file and let Ranger choose which program to use to open it with (via rifle), just press Enter. To choose yourself, press r, and either choose from the list or type the program you want to use. You can also use the command :open_with.
>
> To add a file handler to Ranger's repertoire, run the command ranger --copy-config=rifle, then edit the resulting file.

In `~/.config/ranger/rifle.conf` look for the section

```
# Video/Audio with a GUI
```

It has samples for some players, e.g.:

```
mime ^video|audio, has vlc,      X, flag f = vlc -- "$@"
```

Of course you need to have vlc (or any of the listed) installed for this to work. Otherwise copy the line and add your own.

Afterwards pressing `enter` or `l` in ranger should open file in your player.

Comment: I have downloaded vlc, but it says label not specified or something like that. Do I replace the @ with the path?

Comment: Can you run vlc from the commandline? Then it should just work with the defaults.

Comment: cant run it from the commandline

Comment: You need to add it to your path